# PHP, Google Data API V3, Upload to youtube

Tags: php, youtube

I am trying to implement code to upload a video to youtube.  I saw a couple of other posts about this topic but I still cannot get it to work and am not skilled enough to figure out how to test it to see what is happening.  I can also run the framework of this code and get the contents that have been uploaded but I just cannot seem to upload a video.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php

// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/src/Google_Client.php');
require_once ($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php');
session_start();

/* You can acquire an OAuth 2 ID/secret pair from the API Access tab on the Google APIs Console
  <http://code.google.com/apis/console#access>
For more information about using OAuth2 to access Google APIs, please visit:
  <https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2>
Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project. */
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 'someclient.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = 'some secret';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
  FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);

$youtube = new Google_YoutubeService($client);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate();
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
    print "line 38";
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    print "line 40";
    $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test descrition");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1","tag2"));
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "private";

    $video = new Google_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    $error = true;
    $i = 0;

    try {
        $obj = $youTubeService->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
                                         array("data"=>file_get_contents("screencast.mp4"), 
                                        "mimeType" => "video/mp4"));
    } catch(Google_ServiceException $e) {
        print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage(). " <br>";
        print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: What error you're getting?

Comment: You should be skilled enough at least to provide an error, instead of "oh it jsut not workin, help"

Comment: I am not quite sure what the error is.  I think there is an issue with the statement if ($client->getAccessToken()) because I can tell its not getting into the statement.  So I tried removing it to see if I could generate an error but there were no errors printed.  I am new to php and the google api so I am trying to put together code samples to be able to upload a video.